# How to access template instance from helpers in Meteor 0.8.0 Blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor

The [change in behavior for the `Template.foo.rendered` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22795437/586086) in Meteor 0.8.0 means that we don't get to automatically use the rendered callback as a way to manipulate the DOM whenever the contents of the template change. One way to achieve this is by using reactive helpers as in https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback. The reactive helpers should theoretically help performance by only being triggered when relevant items change.

However, there is now a new problem: the helper no longer has access to the template instance, like the `rendered` callback used to. This means that anything used to maintain state on the template instance cannot be done by helpers.

Is there a way to access both the template instance's state as well as use reactive helpers to trigger DOM updates in Blaze?

Comment: You can always define an UI.Component with custom `render` function. See for example my answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789821/meteor-0-8-blaze-how-to-update-rendered-changes-for-jquery-plugins/22791642#22791642).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the latest versions you can use more convenient [`Template.instance()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_instance) instead.

Answer (score 12):

Now there's [`Template.instance()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_instance) which allows you to access a template's instance in helpers. e.g

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    myvalue: function() {
        var tmpl = Template.instance();

        ...
    }
});
```

Along with reactiveDict, you could use them to pass values down set in the rendered callback.

```
Template.myTemplate.created = function() {
    this.templatedata = new ReactiveDict();

}
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
    this.templatedata.set("myname", "value");
};

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    myvalue: function() {
        var tmpl = Template.instance();
        return tmpl.templatedata.get('myname');
    }
});
```

Comment: UI._templateInstance() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently being tracked as "one of the first things to be added" in post 0.8.0 Meteor:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1529

Another related issue is the ability to access data reactively in the rendered callback, which avoids this issue in the first place:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2010